# CALL_EXCEPTION in estimateGas with local ganache

Tags: ethers.js, nodejs, ganache

I am trying to *deploy a contract to a local ganache network using Nodejs v20*. Nodejs is able to connect with local Ganache but the deploy() method is giving following error:

> Error: missing revert data (action="estimateGas", data=null,
> reason=null, transaction={ "data":
> "0x608060405234801561000f575f8....", "from": "0xfeBaeDDecD30....",
> "to": null }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION,
> version=6.6.1)

```
info: {
    error: {
      message: 'VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode',
      stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n' +
        '    at exactimate (C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\GanacheUI_2.7.1.0_x64__rb4352f0jd4m2\\app\\resources\\static\\node\\node_modules\\ganache\\dist\\node\\1.js:2:182136)',
      code: -32000,
      name: 'RuntimeError',
      data: [Object]
    },
    payload: {
      method: 'eth_estimateGas',
      params: [Array],
      id: 4,
      jsonrpc: '2.0'
    }
  }
```

It is trying to call this eth_estimateGas function and it fails. I am using solcjs to compile the Solidity contract using the command

> solcjs --bin --abi  SimpleStorage.sol

These are the versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ethers": "^6.6.1",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "solc": "0.7"
 }
```

**Below is the code for Nodejs**

```
async function main() {
  // http://127.0.0.1:7545  RPC URL for Ganache
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://192.168.2.17:8545");

  const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
    "0xe75a169f....",
    provider
  );

  provider.getCode()

  const abi = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi").toString()
  );
  const binary = fs
    .readFileSync("./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin")
    .toString();

  const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
  await contractFactory.deploy();
}
```

**Below is the code for the smart contract**

```
*// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.6;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 public favoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public virtual {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using the below versions of both `solcjs` & `Solidity`

> 0.8.19

Also while compiling the code with `solcjs` make sure the version is `0.8.19`
I used `npx solcjs` for this

Answer (score 1):

i was able to fix my problem by giving the gas prices and the gas limit

```
  const overrides = {
    gasLimit: 6721975, // Adjust the gas limit as needed
    gasPrice: ethers.parseUnits("20000000000", "wei"), // Adjust the gas    price as needed
  };
const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(overrides);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using a newer version of [solc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc) and was seeing the same error. To fix:

1. `yarn remove solc`
2. `yarn add solc@0.8.7-fixed`
3. Recompile contract and deploy